# jqGrid. Can't create delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use * jqGrid  5.1.0
i find documentation. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons
It's rather easy by docs, but after adding such code, my jqGrid don't add buttons. There are no mistakes in console. Also, last extra col for this button don't appears.
I will be grateful for the help

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "/backend.php",
    datatype: "xml",
    mtype: "POST",
    colNames: ["Клиент", "id", "Адрес", "Дата", "Время", "Водитель","Оборудование", "Примечание"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "name", width: 80, align: "center", editable: true, sorttype:'string', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']}},
        { name: "order_id", width: 80, align: "center", sorttype:'integer', searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}},
        { name: "address", width: 160, align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: "date", width: 80, align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: "time", width: 80, align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: "driver", width: 80, align: "center", editable: false },
        { name: "equip", width: 100, align: "center", editable: true },
        { name: "notice", width: 80, align: "center", editable: true },
    ],
    pager: "#pager",
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    viewrecords: true,
    onSelectRow: function(id){ if(id && id!==lastsel && lastsel!=0){ jQuery('#list').jqGrid('saveRow',lastsel); jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true); lastsel=id; }else{ if(lastsel==0){ jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true); lastsel=id; } } },
    editurl: "/iwater/backend.php",
    gridview: true,
    autoencode: false,
    caption: "Заказы",
    loadonce: true,
    sortable:true
});
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false}).navButtonAdd('#pager',{
    caption:"Del",
    buttonicon:"ui-icon-del",
    onClickButton: function(){
        alert("Deleting Row");
    },
    position:"last"
});
$("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{searchOperators : true});
$("#list").jqGrid('setGridHeight',300);
```

Answer (score 0):

The option `buttonicon:"ui-icon-del"` is wrong. The value should be one from jQuery UI CSS Framework Icons (see [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/) for details). I suppose that you wanted to use the name `ui-icon-trash` instead of `ui-icon-del`.

Depend on other parts of your code, the call `.navButtonAdd('#pager',{...` could be illegal too. The call in the form `.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{...` works always.

Finally I want to mention that jqGrid 5.1.0 is Guriddo jqGrid JS, which is commercial product available for the prices found [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is **alternative** fork of jqGrid which I develop and which is available under old MIT/GPL-licenses completely free of charge. You can consider to use it instead of jqGrid 5.1.0. I suppose that your current code is full compatible with free jqGrid. You can try it by usage URLs to jqGrid files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).